# Django url paths what is optimal number to cover all combinations

Tags: django, django-urls

Example: Car Website.

---

If you have a URL structure that goes like this /maker/model/year. Where maker, model, year are the generic default placeholder for any. And replace any part will filter the results.

So:

- `/maker/` will list give you a list of car makers like VW or Ford.
- `/Ford/model/` will list all models made by Ford
- `/maker/model_of_car/` will list all models with that name (if two makers have the same name of the model it will list both.
- `/maker/model/` will list all models
- etc... if you need more example please say. But I hope this is enough to get the idea across.

What is the optimal number of URLs need to cover all possibility? Can you show if not all, a critical number of example to get the idea across. So in the form `url(r'(?P<maker>[w-]+)/(?P<model>[w-]+/)'` (**optimal** meaning: **NOT** making just making one super URL that will require a complex view and template to make it work.)

I am sorry about the question name, can someone change it to fit the body (if required). I feel like it does not do the body justice.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for your needs, but I think you should rethink your url convention. Look at how Django Rest Framework builds it's ViewSet's urls. it will work great for you

```
url(r'^maker/$', <view>),
url(r'^maker/model/$', <view>),
url(r'^maker/(?P<model_of_car>[\w ]+)/$', <view>),
url(r'^(?P<maker>[\w ]+)/model/$', <view>),
```